# DirectoryExists return False when service check on network folder

Tags: service, delphi-2007

I'm trying to check directory existence in network folder using delphi function DirectoryExists in service app. Address like //[ip address]/thefolder. Folder is exists in network pc. But always give result as False (not found) when using this function. But when I use DirectoryExists in non service app ( desktop app ), the function give result True ( folder exists / found ). I already read all articles about DirectoryExists, but still not works ( most talking about desktop app ).

I'm using Delphi 2007.
Using Windows Server 2012 and Windows XP.

```pascal
implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure TsvcMyService.ServiceStart(Sender: TService;
var Started: Boolean);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled:=True;
end;

procedure TsvcMyService.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if DirectoryExists(\\[ip address]\NetworkFolder) then
  begin
    LogMessage(' Exists !',EVENTLOG_SUCCESS,0,1234);
  end else
  begin
    LogMessage(' Not Exists !',EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE,0,1234);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The issue is the context in which the service runs, e.g. the log on user that you specify in the service manager

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get it. What I suppose to do? Maybe for example. Thank you for your respond.

Comment: First of all, find out what user is used to run the service

Comment: Ok. I'm using user administrator in my pc where my service app runs.

Comment: No. In the service manager control panel applet. What is the logon user for the service?

Comment: Ok. I open service applet ( Win+R, type services.msc ), right click my service app, click Properties, then I go to Log On tab. It selected Log on as: Local System account

Comment: Thee you go. That account doesnt see these volumes or drives or directories. Note that it is usually bad practise to use the local system account.

Comment: O I see. Ok. What I suppose to do then? I should select "This Account" ? Fill with my username and my password Windows login?

Comment: You need to decide which account to use. I can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Local System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/localsystem-account) account does not have access to network resources.

See [Service User Accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-user-accounts).

Try the [Network Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/networkservice-account) or [Local Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/localservice-account) account instead. Or, create an actual user account that has the network permissions you need.

Comment: I select "This account" and type "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService". Set Password and Confirm password blank. Click Apply button. Then start the service. Service not running a log (I created log in service to see what happend). What do I miss ? Thank you.

Comment: @DoubleU I can't answer that since you have not shown any of your service code, or what kind of logging you are using

Comment: @DoubleU why are you trying to write to a text file in the Windows System folder? Don't do that. User accounts, including LocalService and NetworkService, do not have access to do that. Use the system log instead, via the [Event Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/eventlog/event-logging) or [Windows Event Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/windows-event-log) APIs, which are specifically designed for this purpose

Comment: Thanks for info about logging in service app. It's made for easy reading purpose log only and hidden. Ok, I try change the code in how to make a log.

Comment: Text file, If not in the Windows System folder, is it ok?

Comment: @DoubleU sure, if you write it to a folder you have rights to write to. Which is not the system folder